# Convert long long int to string date time in chrono c++

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

So, I have a long long int number from a c++ function that I think represents time since epoch in chrono. I want to convert it to string in microseconds precise string time in format for example 2019-12-05 13:50:10.123456 (the second part is 6 digit precise). I have used chrono for time now using system_clock::now(); but I am confused if the input is long long int. It seems the chrono library doesn't have any function with long long int as input. Can you help me? I am newbie in c++.

Comment: "represents time since epoch" - what kind of time? Number of nanoseconds since the beginning of the epoch? Seconds? Milliseconds? Days?  What does the number *mean*?

Comment: it is in trillions so maybe nanoseconds or microseconds.

Comment: If you don't know, we don't know either.  Fwiw, today it is about 1.5 trillion milliseconds since the 1970 epoch.

Comment: Yes, it is around 1.5 trillion so it is in milis. I have successfully change to string in python using datetime library. I just don't know how to do it in c++.